# How to store object of inherited class in HashMap as key (Couldn't preserve child class properties)

Tags: json, spring-boot, inheritance, hashmap, google-dfp

I'm trying to store object of a class "OrderForCalendar" inherited from ["Order" class of DFP](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-publishers/docs/reference/v201708/OrderService.Order). But the resulting JSON doesn't contain the custom attributes of inherited class.

**Inherited class: OrderForCalendar**

```
import com.google.api.ads.dfp.axis.v201708.Order;

public class OrderForCalendar extends Order
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String campaignCalendarStatus;
    /**
     * @return the campaignCalendarStatus
     */
    public String getCampaignCalendarStatus()
    {
        return campaignCalendarStatus;
    }
    /**
     * @param campaignCalendarStatus the campaignCalendarStatus to set
     */
    public void setCampaignCalendarStatus(String campaignCalendarStatus)
    {
        this.campaignCalendarStatus = campaignCalendarStatus;
    }
}
```

As you can see, "campaignCalendarStatus" is the only attribute I've added in the inherited class.
Now, I've a HashMap,

`HashMap <OrderForCalendar, ArrayList<LineItemForCalendar>> ordLineItemsMap = new HashMap<>();`,
which stores "OrderForCalendar" as key and ArrayList of "LineItemForCalendar" as value.

```
if (orderPage.getResults() != null)
                for (Order order : orderPage.getResults())
                {
                    OrderForCalendar orderForCalendar = new OrderForCalendar();
                    BeanUtils.copyProperties(order, orderForCalendar);
                    orderForCalendar.setCampaignCalendarStatus(queryKey);
                    ordLineItemsMap.put(orderForCalendar, ordIdLineItemsMap.get(orderForCalendar.getId()));
                }
            jElem = gObj.toJsonTree(ordLineItemsMap);
```

Explanation:

**orderPage:** Array of Orders of type DFP's ["Order"](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-publishers/docs/reference/v201708/OrderService.Order).

**BeanUtils.copyProperties(order, orderForCalendar);**: I'm copying parent object to child object.

**orderForCalendar.setCampaignCalendarStatus(queryKey);**: I'm setting some string to the local attribute of OrderForCalendar.

**ordLineItemsMap.put(orderForCalendar, ordIdLineItemsMap.get(orderForCalendar.getId()));**: I'm storing "orderForCalendar" object and its corresponding ArrayList of "LineItemForCalendar" in the HashMap.

**jElem = gObj.toJsonTree(ordLineItemsMap);**: Finally I'm converting that HashMap object to Gson's JsonElement.

When I return `jElem.toString()`, the resulting JSON doesn't contains my custom attribute "*campaignCalendarStatus*" in the OrderForCalendar object.

```
"OrderForCalendar{advertiserId=40595, creatorId=2954556, currencyCode=USD, externalOrderId=0, id=278756, isArchived=false, isProgrammatic=false, lastModifiedByApp=DFP, lastModifiedDateTime=DateTime{date=Date{day=18, month=10, year=2017}, hour=0, minute=19, second=39, timeZoneID=PST8PDT}, name=Livy Active, notes=Ative lines will deliver with unlimited end date., startDateTime=DateTime{date=Date{day=19, month=9, year=2017}, hour=18, minute=11, second=0, timeZoneID=Asia/Dubai}, status=APPROVED, totalBudget=Money{currencyCode=USD, microAmount=0}, totalClicksDelivered=6782, totalImpressionsDelivered=314646, traffickerId=3962, unlimitedEndDateTime=true}"
```

**Complete JSON Result:**

```
{
            "OrderForCalendar{advertiserId=40595, creatorId=2954556, currencyCode=USD, externalOrderId=0, id=278756, isArchived=false, isProgrammatic=false, lastModifiedByApp=DFP, lastModifiedDateTime=DateTime{date=Date{day=18, month=10, year=2017}, hour=0, minute=19, second=39, timeZoneID=PST8PDT}, name=Livy Active, notes=Ative lines will deliver with unlimited end date., startDateTime=DateTime{date=Date{day=19, month=9, year=2017}, hour=18, minute=11, second=0, timeZoneID=Asia/Dubai}, status=APPROVED, totalBudget=Money{currencyCode=USD, microAmount=0}, totalClicksDelivered=6782, totalImpressionsDelivered=314646, traffickerId=3962, unlimitedEndDateTime=true}": [
                {
                    "id": 3455301609,
                    "start": "2017-09-19T18:15:00",
                    "title": "KJH Active",
                    "status": "needs_creative",
                    "description": "DELIVERING",
                    "advertiser_name": "Givenchy",
                    "flag": true
                },
                {
                    "id": 3455822625,
                    "start": "2017-10-16T18:20:00",
                    "title": "KAY Joir",
                    "status": "needs_creative",
                    "description": "PAUSED_INVENTORY_RELEASED",
                    "advertiser_name": "IIlyu",
                    "flag": true
                }
            ]
}
```

It seems the only values of original DFP Order is stored but not custom attribute of the child class.

Please let me know if any more info is required.

Answer (score 0):

The `campaignCalendarStatus` property is actually there.

What happens is that you are using a complex object as a key in your map. This map has no valid JSON representation, as JSON keys must be strings, according to the JSON spec.

So the JSON library you are using to serialize your map fallbacks to what `toString()` returns and uses that as the key. And surely the `Order` class is overriding the `toString()` method, and of course, the `Order` class knows nothing about the new `campaignCalendarStatus` attribute of your `OrderForCalendar` subclass. It just returns something like `this.getClass().getSimpleName() + {field1= + field1Value + ...}`, where `field1..N` correspond to the fields of the `Order` class.

If you want your new attribute to be included, you must override the `toString()` method in your `OrderForCalendar` class and include the value of its `campaignCalendarStatus` field. However, this is not a good approach IMO and you should consider using a string as the key of your map.